# What is the Event that is triggered in datatables.net on an ajax callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'm using the jQuery plugin Datatables

I was loading a lot of information and it was getting laggy in IE so I decided to speed things up by using the ajax functionality.

The issue is that I need to load HTML into the table.

When datatables sends an ajax call to the server for data to populate the table is there an event that is triggered at the callback? I'd like to hijack the response and decode the html before it is populated into the table and I can't find mention of it in the documentation.

Edit: attempt to clarify question. separate question removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`fnServerData`](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks) callback parameter and handle it in the "success" handler of the AJAX call.

```
// POST data to server
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
      $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": function (data) {
          // Do something with the response here
          fnCallback(data);
        }
      } );
    }
  } );
} );
```